# AIR NativeProcess on Mac gives Error:3219, all solutions failing

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air, runtime-error, air-native-extension

I've read up most solutions for this error and none seem to apply.

I'm running a basic AS3 app in FlashBuilder, on OS-X.

- descriptor is set to extendedDesktop
- have set the profile in FB to 'extendedDesktop'
- am publishing as 'signed native installer'
- I've tried launching the file from both:

  - app:/demo.sh
  - file:///Users/visualife/Desktop/AE/demo.sh
- the target file is set to 777 (executable)
- the target file runs fine when directly targetted
- i'm running the exe on the same OS and machine it's created on
- changing the 'demo.sh' file to a jpg etc doesn't change anything

No matter what I try I get told native process is support, everything runs fine until start is called then a Error: 3219 is thrown with no further information.

all help greatly appreciated!

I've included my code below:

```
package {
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.errors.IllegalOperationError;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.NativeProcessExitEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class VauxhallController extends Sprite {

        private var debug_txt:TextField;

        public var process:NativeProcess;
        private var sh:File;

        public function VauxhallController() {
            if (stage) {
                init();
            } else {
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            }
        }

        private function init($e:Event=null):void {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            build();

            if (NativeProcess.isSupported) {
                initListeners();

                debugMe("Native process supported");

                go();
            } else {
                debugMe("Native not supported");
            }
        }

        private function build():void {
            // debug
            debug_txt   = new TextField();
            debug_txt.width = 300;
            debug_txt.height= 600;
            this.addChild(debug_txt);

        }
        private function initListeners():void { }
        private function go():void {
            runShellFile();
        }

        private function runShellFile():void {
            debugMe("runShellFile");
            var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
            var essArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();            
            var file:File; 

            file    = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("AE/demo.sh");
            debugMe("path|"+ File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("AE/demo.sh").url);

            nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory   = File.desktopDirectory;
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

            process = new NativeProcess();
            process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
            process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
            process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
            process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
            process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);

            try {
                process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
            } catch (error:IllegalOperationError) {
                debugMe(error.toString());
            } catch (error:ArgumentError) {
                debugMe(error.toString());
            } catch (error:Error) {
                debugMe(error.toString());
            }

            debugMe("# DONE");
        }

        public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void {    debugMe("Got: "+ process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));   }
        public function onErrorData(event:ProgressEvent):void {     debugMe("ERROR: "+ process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable));   }
        public function onExit(event:NativeProcessExitEvent):void { debugMe("Process exited with: "+ event.exitCode);   }
        public function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void {        debugMe("IOError: "+ event.toString());             }

        private function debugMe(_str:String):void {    debug_txt.appendText(_str +"\n");   }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the entire error please.

Comment: Hi BotMaster, unfortunately the error tracing out is simply "Error: 3219"

there doesn't appear to be any further information unless I'm missing it...

to confirm: the code compiles fine, the error is at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this article?
http://www.actionscripterrors.com/?p=2527

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop desktop</supportedProfiles>
```

Comment: yes Mika, thanks for the suggestion but that's one of the articles I followed originally and hence the list things above that I've tried. But it still isn't working.

Comment: Is the path from debugMe("path|"... valid?

Comment: yes, the app traces out:
file:///Users/visualife/Desktop/AE/demo.sh

which when copied into the Finder it launches the correct file

Comment: Weird I tested your code and got it working fine with a release build : Native process supported
runShellFile
path|file:///Users/mika/Desktop/AE/run.sh
# DONE
Got: OK!

Comment: really? wow. thanks for checking Mika. And the run.sh ran?

any chance you could possibly share your source as I must therefore be missing something in the setup. can email me direct on rich@visualife.co.uk if that's easier.

Comment: I'll send you a zip archive shortly

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and in my case is because I'm trying to open .exe on MacOS. Verify if your demo.sh script interacts with .exe files.